# Python Super Resolution Keras issue

Tags: python, keras

I'm having an issue i can't manage to solve.
I'm just approaching the Super Resolution Images on Python and i found this on github: https://github.com/titu1994/Image-Super-Resolution
I think this is exactly what i need for my project.
So i just install everything i need to run it and i run it with this:
python main.py (path)t1.bmp

t1.bmp is an image stored in the "input-images" directory so my command is this:

python main.py C:\Users\cecilia....\t1.bmp

The error i get is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg2aZ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXgYb.jpg

Can you please help me solving this? (The code i'm using is the one on the github i linked)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The very first line on the Readme in the github link that you give says that the code is designed for theano only. Yet in your traceback it shows that you are using tensorflow as backend...

The error that you are having is typical of having the wrong image format for the used backend. You have to know that for convolutional networks, Theano and tensorflow have different conventions. Theano expects the following order for the dimensions (batch, channels, nb_rows , nb_cols) and tensorflow (batch, nb_rows, nb_cols, channels). The first is known as "channels_first" and the other "channels_last". So what happens is that the code you are trying to run (which is explicitly said to be designed for Theano) organises the data to match the channels_first format, which causes tensorflow to crash because the dimensions don't match what it expects.

Bottom line: use theano, or change the code appropriately to make it work on tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that